# javaScript and Regex, replace last occurence on string with another string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
const test = 'a,b,c,d'
```

I want to have:

```
a, b, c and d // each comma has an extra space at right
```

I tried some regex like:

```
test.replaceAll(',', ', ').replace(/,([^,]*)$/, '$1');
```

But that will remove last occurence, how could I change it for another string, in this case with `and` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex replacement approach:

```js
var test = 'a,b,c,d';
var output = test.replace(/,/g, ', ').replace(/,(?!.*,)/, " and");
console.log(output);
```

In the second replacement, the regex `,(?!.*,)` targets the last comma using a negative lookahead asserting that no further commas occur in the input.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non regex approach

```js
let test = 'a,b,c,d'.split(",");
let last = test.splice(-1);
test = test.join(", ") + " and " + last;
console.log(test)
```